# How to Crop Multiple Objects in an Image [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I'm freshman to MATLAB  & Developing "Rice Quality Identification" Application using MATLAB & NEURAL NETWORK .For my Guidance I'm preferring this [Research Paper](http://ijret.org/Volumes/V02/I11/IJRET_110211082.pdf)

This Application Comprises with 5 Phases

1. Image Acquisition
2. Image Pre-processing
3. Image Segmentation and Identifying Region of Interest
4. Feature Extraction
5. Training and Testing

I'm now in 3rd Phase , Already developed initial steps for this application

Step 1: Browse Image from Computer and Show it

```
 % Get the orginal image & show , Figure 1
 [fileName, pathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg;*.tif;*.png;*.gif','Select the Picture file');
 I = fullfile(pathName, fileName);
 I = imread(I);
 imshow(I)
```

[image]

Step 2: Background subtraction

```
% selected rice image Background subtraction , Figure 2
% Use Morphological Opening to Estimate the Background
background = imopen(I,strel('disk',7));
I2 = I - background;
figure, imshow(I2);
```

[image]

Step 3:

```
% get the Black and white Image , Figure 3
% output image BW replaces all pixels in the input image with luminance greater than 0.17 level  
BW = im2bw(I2,0.17);
figure, imshow(BW)
```

[image]

Step 4:

```
 % Remove small objects fewer than 30 pixels from binary image
 pure = bwareaopen(BW,30);
 figure, imshow(pure)
```

[image]

Step 5: Labeling

```
% Label Black and white & Image bounding box around each object
L=bwlabel(pure,8);
bb=regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
```

I'm Sticking at Step 6 since 2 days. Step 6 is crop multiple objects from original image using Labeled Binary Image

which is exactly output should get like below image ,

[image]

if I can get this I can easily calculate Morphological Features and Color features for each object in that original image , to use for phase 4 .

Morphological Features

```
1.Area for each Object
2.scale of X, Y axis for each object in above picture
3.using X, Y axis I can Calculate Aspect Ratio
```

Color features

```
 1. Red Mean 
 2. Green Mean 
 3. Blue Mean
```

Can you please explain the way to **crop multiple objects from original image using Labeled Binary Image** which is Step 6.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting Step #6 right, I believe what it's saying is that they want you to **segment out** the final objects after Step #5 using the binary map that you have produced.  Given your comments, you also want to **extract** the bounding boxes delineated in Step #5 as well.  If that's the case, then all you have to do is use the `RegionProps` structure defined in `bb` that will help us do this for you.  As a bit of review for you, the `BoundingBox` field of a `RegionProps` structure for each object extracted from the image returns an array of 4 numbers like so:

```
[x y w h]
```

`x` denotes the column / horizontal co-ordinate, `y` denotes the row / vertical co-ordinate, and `w,h` denote the width and height of the bounding box.

All you need to do is create a binary map, and cycle through each bounding box to delineate where we need to cut out of the image.  When you're done, use this binary map to extract out your pixels.  In other words:

```
%//Initialize map to zero
bMap = false(size(pure));

%//Go through each bounding box
for i = 1 : numel(bb)
    %//Get the i'th bounding box
    bbox = bb(i).BoundingBox;

    %//Set this entire rectangle to true
    %//Make sure we cast off any decimal
    %//co-ordinates as the pixel locations
    %//are integer
    bbox = floor(bbox);
    bMap(bbox(2):bbox(4), bbox(1):bbox(3)) = true;
end

%//Now extract our regions
out = zeros(size(I));
out = cast(out, class(I)); %//Ensures compatible types

%//Extract cropped out regions for each channel
for i = 1 : size(out,3)
    chanOut = out(:,:,i);
    chanIm = I(:,:,i);
    chanOut(bMap) = chanIm(bMap);
    out(:,:,i) = chanOut;
end
```

This creates an output image stored in `out`, and copies only those pixels that are true from each channel over, based on each bounding box given in Step #5.

I believe this is what Step #6 is talking about.  Let me know if I have interpreted this properly.

Comment: you figured out what I intended exactly, but I need to clear this

"How can I Visualize the those mapped individual objects in one figure like above picture ? Do I need use "for loop" to do that ? "

I'm really appriciate your help on this situation

Comment: Do you want to create a single image that contains all of those objects **with the bounding boxes** intact?

Comment: Yeah ,that's it,  Then I can easily measure Morphological Features and Color features for each object,

Comment: Ok.  You'll need to give me a few minutes to modify my answer.  We can use the values from `regionprops` to crop out each bounding box from the original image

Comment: I still unable to get image output like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/VZBz9.jpg  ,

 is this problem with MATLAB version ? I'm using MATLAB R2013a

Comment: If you want an output like that.... just add a shade of gray to the background.  Honestly, you **don't** need to replicate the exact figure they have.  What you have done to segment out the objects is good enough.  You can use those bounding boxes to compute all of your descriptors.  If you really want to reproduce the figure they have, change this line of code: `out = zeros(size(I));` to this: `out = 128*ones(size(I));`

Comment: @kelum: Do you require further assistance?

Comment: using "Blobs analysis" I able to mark bound boxes for each object in an image , but now I'm trying to extract Morphological Features and Color features in that bound-boxes

Comment: @kelum: Please make that another question.  What you have asked here I believe I have adequately answered.